# How to enable zoom for two different UIScrollview in single UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

I am displaying two images on single view where both images must have zoom functionality.My page height is around 1000 pixels and images must be display on top and bottom of page. For that I have added two different scroll view and added image views on `scroll views`.

Now Zoom is working properly for second image .But first image is getting displayed in top left corner of `scroll view` once zoomed out. It seems there are two images.

Here is the delegate method i am using:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return [[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Is there anything i am missing ? or is this not really possible to enable zoom when there are two `scroll views` for single page.

Comment: did you try to setContentOffSet?

Comment: Yes , i tried now but still same issue is coming. I am able to zoom image but a copy of image also appears on left corner of scroll view.

Comment: Can you try using tag value for scrollview?

Comment: I am using tag value but it's not affecting the zoom feature even if i am not using it.

Comment: Problem was not related to zoom functionality. It was there because i was recreating image view when page is reloaded.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code its working for enable zoom when there are two scroll views for single page.

> //Create First ImageView

```
image1 =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220)];
image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
image1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

> //Create and Set Values for Scrollview 1

```
scroll1 =[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220)];
scroll1.contentSize = image1.frame.size;
[scroll1 setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[scroll1 setMaximumZoomScale:4.0];
scroll1.delegate = self;
scroll1.clipsToBounds = YES;
scroll1.tag =0;
[scroll1 addSubview:image1];
image1.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
scroll1.zoomScale = 1;
[self.view addSubview:scroll1];
```

> Second Scrollview and ImageView
>
> // Create Second ImageView

```
image2 =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260)];
image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
image2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

> // Create Second ScrollView

```
scroll2 =[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 220, 320, 260)];
scroll2.contentSize = image2.frame.size;
[scroll2 setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[scroll2 setMaximumZoomScale:4.0];
scroll2.delegate = self;
scroll2.clipsToBounds = YES;
scroll2.tag =1;
[scroll2 addSubview:image2];

image2.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
scroll2.zoomScale = 1;
[self.view addSubview:scroll2];
```

This will help you, since it is already working for me.

Delegate method as follow:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.tag ==0) {
        return image1;
    }
    else return image2;
}
```